# jQuery Ajax - no success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`success` in my AJAX call doesn't trigger at all, and I can't figure out why. None of the alerts specified in the AJAX file are popping up.

The form:

```
<form onsubmit="check_reg();return false;" method="post" name="reg_form" id="reg">
    <label class="error" id="reg_error"></label>
    <label for="login_reg">Login</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login_reg" placeholder="Login">
    <label for="email_reg">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_reg" placeholder="Email">
    <label for="haslo_reg">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass_reg" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Register</button>  
</form>
```

reg_script.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $login = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email) VALUES('$login', '$password', '$email')")) {
        echo "ok";
    } 
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "empty";
}
```

AJAX

```
function check_reg() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reg_script.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: "login=" + $('#login_reg').val() + "&password=" + $('#pass_reg').val() + "&email=" + $('#email_reg').val(),
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 'ok') {
                alert('ok');
            }
            else if (result == 'error') {
                alert('error');
            }
            else if (result == 'empty') {
                alert('empty');
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

EDIT: I should've added that I used this tutorial: http://developertips.net/post/display/web/3/dynamic-login-form-with-ajax-php/ and managed to get the login form working just fine, it's just the registration form that's acting up.

Comment: I think maybe it should be if result.responseText when you're checking for ok/empty/error

Comment: before you echo anything to the client echo Content-type: text/html. Have you checked what the request/response looks like using firebug/chrome developer tools or fiddler? This can tell you a lot about what was sent to the server and how the server handled the request

Comment: Does `error` trigger?

Comment: try `if ( $.trim(result) == 'ok') { ...`, and build the data as an object.

Comment: What if you just use `alert(result)` to see if anything comes back at all?

Comment: So I did what Alec said, and added a simple `alert(result)` before the `if`s, and it turns out that the result does indeed end up equal to what I want ('empty' if any of the fields are empty, 'ok' if they're filled out correctly etc.). Why is it not triggering the `if`s then?

Comment: @user1170027 - you did of course try my suggestion above ?

Comment: @adeneo Yup. Didn't make any difference, sadly.

Comment: @adeneo I take that back, it works! I think I love you.

Comment: You're welcome, extra spaces is almost always the problem when everything else seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form onsubmit="check_reg();return false;" method="post" name="reg_form" id="reg">
<label class="error" id="reg_error"></label>
<label for="login_reg">Login</label>
<input type="text" name="login" id="login_reg" placeholder="Login">
<label for="email_reg">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email_reg" placeholder="Email">
<label for="haslo_reg">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="pass_reg" placeholder="Password">
<button type="submit">Register</button>  
</form>
```

to:

```
<form>
<label class="error" id="reg_error"></label>
<label for="login_reg">Login</label>
<input type="text" name="login" id="login_reg" placeholder="Login">
<label for="email_reg">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email_reg" placeholder="Email">
<label for="haslo_reg">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="pass_reg" placeholder="Password">
<input type="button" onclick="check_reg()">Register</button>  
</form>
```

That way, your HTML file will call your check_reg() which then calls your php-file. You don't need method=post and so on in HTML-file. All this information is already in your function.

Btw, your data-attribute in check_reg() function, I recommend that you change that to serializeArray() instead.

One more thing I just realized:

```
success: function(result) {
```

The result-variable contains the error-messages form the serverside (php). so all you have to do is:

```
success: function(result) {
             alert(result);
```

Comment: Bah, I should've thought of adding the `alert(result)` line to the script before. It turns out that the values 'ok' and 'empty' are being assigned to `request` correctly, but why won't the `if`s trigger then?

Comment: Im not completely sure, but it COULD be because 'ok' is in single quotation marks, while result referres to "ok" (double quotation marks)

Comment: Tried changing the quotation marks around and no, that's not it either.

Comment: Before your first if-statement, echo/alert out result, just to see what the variable contains. In addition to that can you try '===' instead of just '=='. '===' checks the type AND value :)

Comment: Saw this just now. After your 'else if' brackets, there is an end-bracket with a ','(comma) after it. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using POST request, but sending data as querystring as used for GET request.

Use data in form of object:

```
 data: {'login': $('#login_reg').val() ,'password':$('#pass_reg').val() ,'email':$('#email_reg').val()}
```

You can also check with `print_r($_POST)` in your php file, so that you can see, whether data is posted or not.

So use follwing code in ajax:

```
function check_reg() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reg_script.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'login': $('#login_reg').val() ,'password':$('#pass_reg').val() ,'email':$('#email_reg').val()},
        success: function(result) {
            if (result == 'ok') {
                alert('ok');
            }
            else if (result == 'error') {
                alert('error');
            }
            else if (result == 'empty') {
                alert('empty');
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: The data is posted, I can add users to the database just fine. I've tried changing the `data` option around, but it doesn't seem to help at all. Also I've used the POST request before in my login form with the GET query string and it worked just fine, so I'm not sure if that's where the issue is.